# replacing a missing value in R with average value

Tags: r, if-statement, average, missing-data

I have a dataframe with columns of data with missing value and I would like to replace the missing value by taking the mean using the value of the cells above and below.

```
 df1<-c(2,2,NA,10, 20, NA,3)
 if(df1[i]== NA){
 df1[i]= mean(df1[i+1],df1[i-1])
}
```

However, I am getting this error

```
  Error in if (df1[i] == NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
  In addition: Warning message:
  In if (df1[i] == NA) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Any guidance would be appreciated to solve this issue.

Comment: What if you have two NA values in a row? What if the first or last element is missing?

Comment: I used the df1 as an example but my dataset consists of thousands of values, and NA's are found not to be consecutive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure you don't have any consecutive NA values and the first and last elements are never NA, then you can do

```
df1<-c(2,2,NA,10, 20, NA,3)
idx<-which(is.na(df1))
df1[idx] <- (df1[idx-1] + df1[idx+1])/2
df1
# [1]  2.0  2.0  6.0 10.0 20.0 11.5  3.0
```

This should be more efficient than a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Using lag and lead from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1[is.na(df1)] <- (df1[is.na(lag(df1, default=""))] +          
                    df1[is.na(lead(df1, default=""))]) / 2
```

This will be much faster than the for loop version

Answer (score 2):

You could use `na.approx()` from the `zoo` package to replace `NA` with interpolated values:

```
library(zoo)
> na.approx(df1)
# [1]  2.0  2.0  6.0 10.0 20.0 11.5  3.0
```

---

As per mentioned by @G.Grothendieck, this will fill the `NA`s if there are multiple `NA`s in a row. Also if there can be `NA`s at the ends then adding the argument `na.rm = FALSE` will preserve them or adding `rule = 2` will replace them with the first or last non-`NA`.

Comment: It shoujld be pointed out that this solution is the only one that fills the NAs if there are multiple NAs in a row.   Also if there can be NAs at the ends then adding the argument `na.rm=FALSE` will preserve them or adding `rule=2` will replace them with the first or last non-NA.

Answer (score 1):

to check for NAs use `is.na()`, make a loop and give `mean()` a vector as an argument, otherwise it will only see the first value. This should work if you have no consecutive NAs and first and last entry are non-NA:

```
df1<-c(2,2,NA,10, 20, NA,3)
for(i in 2:(length(df1)-1)){
  if(is.na(df1[i])){
     df1[i]= mean(c(df1[i+1],df1[i-1]))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It first check NA's in the respective column, if there is missing value it replaces with the mean of the column else just returns the dataset.

**df$col_name <- ifelse(is.na(df$col_name), ave(df$col_name, 
                            Fun = function(x) mean(x, na.rm ==TRUE)),df$col_name)**